# defining OCaml type structure

Tags: ocaml

I'm new with OCaml and I am trying to define a type to make a deck of cards, what I have now is:

```
type palo = Espada | Basto | Oro | Copa
type valor = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
type carta = Carta of palo*valor
```

what I want to know if there is a way in which I can define a deck as a list of carta with every combination palo - valor available and then "shuffle" it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:
I should probably clarify that this is a Spanish deck and that is why there is no Jack, Queen, King or Ace

Comment: Is your type valor really accepted ? I seriously doubt about it since it doesn't have the syntax : type t = C of type ;-)

Comment: If the answer is ok for you, don't forget to accept it. ;-)

Comment: @Lhooq how do I? Sorry but I'm also new to stackoverflow thank you the answer was great

Comment: Don't you have something you can click on left to my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could, certainly, a good way to do it is a [Fisher-Yates/Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

So, you would create an array of length `12 * 4 = 48` cards and then shuffle it (you can find this shuffle code in [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#OCaml)) and then use `Array.to_list` if you want to keep a list of cards and not an array.

### [EDIT]

I took the liberty of rewriting your types :

```
type palo = Espada | Basto | Oro | Copa
type valor = Uno | Dos | Tres | Quatro | Cinco | Seis | Siete | 
             Ocho | Nueve | Diez | Once | Doce
type carta = palo * valor
```

You don't need to say that `carta` is a `Carta of palo * valor` since you have only one constructor ;-) `carta` will be an alias for the couple `palo * valor`.

But, actually, an easiest way to do would be to have the types :

```
type palo = Espada | Basto | Oro | Copa
type valor = int
type carta = palo * valor
```

and to ensure that your valor can't be greater than 12, for example. It would make the card creation much easier. (For example, doing so :

```
let cards = Array.init 48 (fun i -> 
   let palo = 
     if i < 12 then Espada
     else if i < 24 then Basto 
     else if i < 36 then Oro 
     else  Copa
   in palo, i mod 12 + 1
  )
```

)

### [SECOND EDIT]

If you really want to have your valor types, this is one way to do :

```
type palo = Espada | Basto | Oro | Copa
type valor = Uno | Dos | Tres | Quatro | Cinco | Seis | Siete | 
             Ocho | Nueve | Diez | Once | Doce
type carta = palo * valor

let lv = [Uno; Dos; Tres; Quatro; Cinco; Seis; Siete; 
          Ocho; Nueve; Diez; Once; Doce]

let cards = 
  let new_list p = List.map (fun v -> p, v) lv in
  let l1 = new_list Espada in
  let l2 = new_list Basto in
  let l3 = new_list Oro in
  let l4 = new_list Copa in
  List.rev_append l1 (List.rev_append l2 (List.rev_append l3 l4))
```

As you can see, I created a list of valors and for each `palo` I add the `palo` to each element of this list (since lists are persistent data structures, it gives me a new list, it **does not** modify the previous one) and then I concatenate the four lists.

And an even better way to do :

```
let lp = [Espada; Basto; Oro; Copa]

let cardsb = 
  let new_list p = List.map (fun v -> p, v) lv in
  List.fold_left (fun acc p ->
    List.rev_append (new_list p) acc) [] lp
```

Which uses iterators which is beautiful, so wow, so charming !

The problem os these last methods is that you can't be sure that you put all your constructors in the list and the typing system won't warn you about it. :-(

Comment: Thank you so much, as I mentioned before, I am a newbie, so one less problem to worry about now, I will modify it now.

Comment: This is a classic in type oriented exercises, see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html#toc17

Comment: @Str I thought your comment was about my solution and my list of constructors but no, it was about the cards problem. ;-)

Comment: @Lhooq sorry for that, I just went where the discussion was. Hope you find it interesting as well, the book is from 2001 I think.

Comment: @Str Oh, don't worry, I already read it multiple times but I wanted to try to adapt to Jenaro specific types ;-) But from your comment I thought I missed the solution and I became sad discovering it wasn't that. :-D